# Make "Reference" in Bibliography Smaller / Spacing in Bibliography

Tags: spacing, sectioning, bibliographies

I have trouble making my bibliography section smaller. This is important because I am applying for the NSF Graduate Fellowship and they want everything to fit 2 pages. Here is what it looks like right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[abbr]{harvard}
\usepackage{bib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

This is the body of my essay.


\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\bibliography{bibtex}

\end{document}
```

Note I am using the `apsr` bibliography style. Unfortunately, the bibliography that pops out takes too much space. The word `References` is huge and there exists a space between each work cited. How do I make `References` smaller and/or delete the blank space between each work cited?

Answer (score 2):

Change the definition of the `thebibliography` environment in order to a) typeset the bibliography heading as a subsection instead of a section b) set the lengths `\itemsep` and `\parskip` to 0pt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abbr]{harvard}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \section*{\refname}%
}{%
  \subsection*{\refname}%
}{}{}

\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\section{foo}

This is the body of my essay.

A second paragraph.

\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]